# Java multi threaded event handling

Tags: java, multithreading, events, event-handling

So I'm working on a project where I've got a opengl graphics thread and one of the things I'm wanting to do is to auto-reload shaders when there source file changes. I know I can use the Java Watch API to poll for file modifications easily enough. I was thinking it would be better to run the "Watcher" on a separate thread to keep the graphics rendering from slowing down/hitching. That said the watcher needs to be able to tell the graphics thread when a file has been changed so that I can reload that shaders source code. The problem is in the fact that the if I use an interface and just subscribe the graphics thread to the watcher, the watcher executes the interface implementation under its own thread not the graphics thread.

So my questions is there a way to execute the handler as if it was on the graphics thread, or is that even the proper approach for a situation like this.

[image]

P.S. I'd like to eventually move all my asset loading to separate worker threads in a job queue fashion, if possible the solution to this problem would also work for these other types of tasks?

(Also if this type of code has a specific name I'd love to know, nothing I searched was getting me anywhere)

Edit: Is my only option to store a "on shader source changed" queue in the gl thread then have the watcher append a item to that queue and have something in the gl thread consume it? Or is there a more generic less boilerplate way of doing something as described by the image above?